# Display different Error message after a Limit?

Tags: java

I need to display a error Message.I have declared a counter.Whenever the counter is 3 it has to display a different error message.So i have written the below snippet.
It returns  `error: <identifier> expected` on the declaration.

```
//declaration
private static attempts = 0;

//operation
switch (xmlRpcFault.getFaultCode()) {
                case 403:
                    attempts++;
                    if(attempts = 3)
                    {
                        mErrorMsgId = R.string.username_or_password_incorrect;
                        //reinitialize counter
                        attempts = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    mErrorMsgId = R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull;
                    break;
```

Comment: this does not compile.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, the OP stated that and was asking why.

Comment: any good IDE could tell you.

Answer (score 4):

The statement:

```
if(attempts = 3)
```

probably should be:

```
if (attempts == 3)
```

?

Comment: +1 Although this in itself would not be the source of the described error, it is definitely a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The source of the error you asked about is that you need to specify the actual type of the variable in your declaration. You have:

```
//declaration
private static attempts = 0;
```

You probably mean:

```
//declaration
private static int attempts = 0;
```

Note the `int` (or whatever type you want it to be).

Also, [the issue that Harmlezz mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691509/616460) (`attempts = 3` vs. `attempts == 3`) is another problem.

---

As an aside: Most of the code you posted, as well as the question you asked, was irrelevant. The correct code to post would have been only the line with the compiler error. The correct question is "why does 'private static attempts = 0' cause a compiler error". Even the tags: This was not an Android question, or a question about while loops or if statements or counters. I mention this constructively: Think about the problem at hand, and try narrowing it down. It's a general thought process that will help you in all cases.

Granted, by posting all of it, it let us spot a few other issues, but that was incidental; your general problem solving thought-process did not match the problem itself.

Question titles are a good window into a person's thought process; in general, you can learn a lot by reexamining your question titles here after your problem is solved.